# IVssBackupComponents::InitializeForBackup fails

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-10

IVssBackupComponents::InitializeForBackup failes with E_UNEXPECTED error.
And in the Event viewer there are two errors:

**Error 1**

```
Volume Shadow Copy Service error: A critical component required by
    the Volume Shadow Copy service is not registered. This might
    happened if an error occurred during Windows setup or during
    installation of a Shadow Copy provider. 

   The error returned from
        CoCreateInstance on class with CLSID
        {e579ab5f-1cc4-44b4-bed9-de0991ff0623} and Name IVssCoordinatorEx2
        is [0x80040154, Class not registered ].

    Operation:
       Instantiating VSS server
```

**Error 2**

```
Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine
    CoCreateInstance.  hr = 0x80040154, Class not registered.

    Operation:
      Instantiating VSS server
```

I have created simple "hello world" VSS program:

```
#include "vss.h"
#include "vswriter.h"
#include <VsBackup.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
#define CHECK_PRINT(result) printf("%s %#08x\n",result==S_OK?"S_OK":"error", result)
  HRESULT  result = CoInitialize(NULL);
  CHECK_PRINT(result);
  IVssBackupComponents *VssHandle;
  result = CreateVssBackupComponents(&VssHandle);
  CHECK_PRINT(result);
  result = VssHandle->InitializeForBackup();
  CHECK_PRINT(result);
  return 0;
}
```

It reports the same output
S_OK 00000000
S_OK 00000000
error 0x80042302

On my main development Windows 10 PC and virtual Windows10 with clean installation.
VSS, swprv services are running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. Debugging the disassembly with looking into the Process Monitor shows that in my case the problem was missing registry key

```
"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{F2C2787D-95AB-40D4-942D-298F5F757874}"
```

google told me that the value should be

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{F2C2787D-95AB-40D4-942D-298F5F757874}]
@="PSFactoryBuffer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{F2C2787D-95AB-40D4-942D-298F5F757874}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,57,00,4f,00,57,00,36,00,34,00,5c,00,76,00,73,00,\
73,00,5f,00,70,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
```

Comment: It's a shame that this hasn't been fixed still.

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, the problem is gone for me when I changed build platform from "Win32"(default option) to "x64". My test environment is a 64-bit Win7.

It should also run as Administrator to avoid "ACCESS DENIED" error(0x80070005).

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down my problem to installing Apple's Bootcamp on my Windows 10 machine. I've read that it fills up the EFI boot volume or something.

So I found the bootcamp's .msi installer, right clicked to get the context menu, then selected uninstall.

All my issues went away.